# Android - CheckedTextView checks wrong element

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_row, null);
        }

        Country item = getItem(position);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country);
        final CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checked);
        ctv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ctv.toggle();
                Country country = (Country) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.d("daim", country.getCountry() + " " + country.getCode());
                //listView.getCheckItemIds();
            }
        });

        tv1.setText(item.getCountry());

        return v;
    }
```

When I check let's say first element (position 0), it gets checked, but when I scroll down the listview, the first position of next "section" gets also checked, this continues all the way down. For instance, I have 100 elements, and I check position 0, then position 10, 20, 30, 40 etc gets also checked. How can handle this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because the listview recycle its view, so it keeps a pool of view that reuse. THe pattern typically I use is:

```
if (this row need to be checked)
        check it
else
        force uncked it
```